# Music player is not working

Tags: 13.04

I am trying to play songs , but it is asking for pluggins. Can anyone help me to overcome with this problem.

Comment: 1. What player are you using?
2. What plugins is it asking for?
3. Why are you having trouble installing said plugins? Do you not know where to find them, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu Restricted Extras in the Ubuntu Software Center.  It will install the needed plugins to play files such as mp3.